# Users with non-ASCII characters in their username break the chat users search function

Tags: bug, chat, search, unicode

If you go to the [chat users page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users) and attempt to search for a username which contains non-ASCII characters, the search doesn't do anything.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Hey, I was breaking chat everyday. <proud>

Comment: @AakashM Was that edit really necessary?

Comment: @Mego no, of course not, but if we made *necessity* a requirement for action then I'm not sure stack exchange would even exist...

Comment: I would love to be able to award this bounty...