# Searching for emoji in chat is  (broken)

Tags: bug, chat, search, emoji

Recently, I've been [recommending music](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118?m=38617332#38617332) in chat, 'tagging' it with emoji ().

But they don't come up in search! https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%F0%9F%8E%B6&room=118

Yea, this is probably waaaaaaaay down the priority list. But it's a nice-to-have.

Comment: Well, same goes for user search: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276747/users-with-non-ascii-characters-in-their-username-break-the-chat-users-search-fu (in chat.)

Comment: It's not really "broken", as I commented in the original bug report, non English characters are just dropped when searching.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hm. It doesn't work; to me, that is broken regardless of the underlying reason. But thanks for digging up the older question - I didn't manage to find that one :\